# Multiple '\=' [Prolog]

Tags: prolog

How can I express the following conjunction more succinctly?

```
condition(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) :- 
    X1 \= X2, 
    X1 \= X3, 
    X1 \= X4, 
    X1 \= X5, 
    X2 \= X3, 
    X2 \= X4, 
    X2 \= X5, 
    X3 \= X4, 
    X3 \= X5, 
    X4 \= X5.
```

Ideally, I want to use a single goal of a built-in / library predicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also opt to define a predicate uniques/1 with maplist/2 that succeeds if the list consists of unique elements. Then your predicate condition/5 would act as calling predicate:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).        % for maplist/2

condition(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) :-
   uniques([X1,X2,X3,X4,X5]).

uniques([]).
uniques([X|Xs]) :-
   maplist(dif(X),Xs),
   uniques(Xs).

?- condition(1,2,3,4,5).
true.

?- condition(1,2,3,4,1).
false.
```

And uniques/1 can be used for arbitrary lists:

```
?- uniques([]).
true.

?- uniques([1,a,6,f(X)]).
true.

?- uniques([A,B,C]).
dif(A, C),
dif(A, B),
dif(B, C).

?- uniques([A,B,A]).
false.

?- uniques(U).
U = [] ;
U = [_G265] ;
U = [_G392, _G395],
dif(_G392, _G395) ;
U = [_G489, _G492, _G495],
dif(_G489, _G495),
dif(_G489, _G492),
dif(_G492, _G495) ;
.
.
.
```

Comment: There is a mistake :   condition(1,2,3,3,4) gives true.

Comment: @joel76: How very stupid of me. I fixed it, thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 5):

It depends...

If all `Xi` are integers and your Prolog supports [finite-domain constraints](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd) ([clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)), just write:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

condition(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) :- 
   all_distinct([X1,X2,X3,X4,X5]).        % use library predicate
```

Comment: Maybe [all_distinct/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=all_distinct/1) would be a better suggestion since [all_different/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=all_different/1) has weaker propagation and the documentation explicitly states "Consider using all_distinct/1 instead,...".

Comment: @tas. Thank you!